# Why is the Bootstrap coloring scheme canceled when the Wicket hops elements?

Tags: java, html, wicket

The HTML of my home page:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 vh-100 p-2" id="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item">Royals of Britain</li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link collapsed text-truncate" href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1">Select a House</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="submenu1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <!-- This is Wicket Markup Git attached panel. -->
                        <ul class="flex-column pl-2 nav" wicket:id="housesDropdown">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" href="#">Oliveira</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML of the Panel

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <li class="nav-item" wicket:id="dropdownLinks"><a class="nav-link py-0" href="/houses/oliveira">Oliveira</a></li>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

So where the hopping becomes relevant is due to the fact that I moved wicket:id="dropdownLinks" from the a element of the Panel HTML to the li element of the Panel HTML. Why does this keep the hyperlinks operational but cancel out the Bootstrap coloring scheme?

EDIT::4/3/2020

Here is the HTML of HousesDropdown

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <li class="nav-item" wicket:id="dropdownLinks"><wicket:child/></li>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Java of HousesDropdown

> package website.fgto.royals_of_britain.view.houses;
>
> import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebMarkupContainer; import
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.BookmarkablePageLink; import
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link; import
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.Panel; import
>   org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RepeatingView; import
>   org.apache.wicket.model.Model; import
>   org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters; import
>   org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;
>
> import website.fgto.royals_of_britain.service.HousesService;
>
> public class HousesDropdown extends Panel {   private static final
>   long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>
> @SpringBean   HousesService housesService;
>
> public HousesDropdown() {
>       add(new WebMarkupContainer(Hyperlink.class));   }
>
> private Link buildDropdownItem(RepeatingView parent, String
>   houseName) {
>       BookmarkablePageLink link =
>           new BookmarkablePageLink(parent.newChildId(), 
>   HouseInformationPage.class, buildPageParameters(houseName));
>
> link.setBody(new Model<>(capitalizedHouseName(houseName)));
>
> return link;   }
>
> private PageParameters buildPageParameters(String houseName) {
>       PageParameters pageParameters = new PageParameters();
>       pageParameters.set("houseName", houseName);
>       return pageParameters;   }
>
> private String capitalizedHouseName(String houseName) {
>       if(houseName.isEmpty()) {
>         return houseName;
>       } else {
>         return houseName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + >houseName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
>       }   } }

Here is the HTML of Hyperlink

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hyperlink</title>
</head>
<body>
<wicket:extend>
    <a class="nav-link py-0" href="/houses/oliveira">Oliveira</a>
</wicket:extend>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Java of Hyperlink

> package website.fgto.royals_of_britain.view.houses;
>
> import org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.RepeatingView; import
>   org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean; import
>   website.fgto.royals_of_britain.service.HousesService;
>
> public class Hyperlink extends HousesDropdown {
>   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
>
> @SpringBean
>   HousesService housesService;
>
> public Hyperlink () {
>   super(id);
>
> add(buildDropdownLinks());
>
> private RepeatingView buildDropdownLinks(){
>   RepeatingView links = new RepeatingView("dropdownLinks");
>
> housesService
>   .findAll()
>   .forEach(
>   (house) -> links.add(buildDropdownItem(links, house.getName()))
>   );
>
> return links;
>   }
>
> } }

Comment: Can you post the finished generated html (Client view) and show the difference? I would guess that the generated html is very likely different and therefor the CSS Rule no longer applies.

Comment: The problem I found was that the Wicket ran the li element and ignored the a element.

Currently I'm erecting a more elaborate set-up with HousesDropdown extends Panel and Hyperlink extends HousesDropdown. More later...